# Why can't I activate Rank-Up-Magic Admiration Of Thousands on duelingnexus.com?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have made a deck with the goal being to reduce my opponents LP to 100 by the effect of [Number C6: Chronomaly Chaos Atlandis](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_C6:_Chronomaly_Chaos_Atlandis).

In order to activate his effect to reduce my opponents LP to I need [Number 6: Chronomaly Atlandis](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_6:_Chronomaly_Atlandis) as an XYZ material so I decided to use the effect of [Gale Dogra](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Gale_Dogra) to send 3 Chronomaly Atlandis's to my graveyard and activate [Rank-Up-Magic Admiration Of Thousands](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Rank-Up-Magic_Admiration_of_the_Thousands) to special summon Chaos Chronomaly Atlandis.

However Rank-Up-Magic Admiration Of Thousands isn't working. **Is there a reason why I have missed?**

Comment: Questions about video game versions of card games are completely on topic here. See [Are questions specifically about the computer version of a game on topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1193/5573) (yes) and [should game-adjacent questions be on topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/5573) (yes). Voting to reopen.

Comment: @AndrewJones inlcuded an answer for you to consider. Also, a clarification, unless you have more than 9000 LP you can't activate Gale Droga's effect 3 times! As each one costs you 3000 LP. Perhaps "3" is not the number you intended to write

Answer (score 1):

> However Rank-Up-Magic Admiration Of Thousands isn't working. Is there a reason why I have missed?

**If you can't activate your RUM it may be because of it's requirements**. From it's text, emphasis mine:

> Target 1 or more Xyz Monsters **in each Graveyard, all of the same Rank**; Special Summon from your Extra Deck, 1 "Number C" or "CXyz" monster that is 1 Rank higher than those monsters, and attach those monsters to it as Xyz Materials. **You cannot Special Summon other monsters during the turn you activate this card**. You can only activate 1 "Rank-Up-Magic Admiration of the Thousands" per turn.

This restricts you because:

1. You have to select **at least 1** monster from **each** graveyard. If your opponent does not have one you can't play that RUM.
2. All the selected monsters have to be of the **same rank**. If neither graveyard contains valid targets you can't activate the RUM.
3. If you **special summoned** something else **previously**, you can't activate the RUM.

All these are possible reasons (besides a bug, naturally) for you not to be able to play the Rank-Up-Magic card.